# Loading First page in UI after scanning

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I want to load the first page scanned (in a scanner attached) in the UI, but right now in this code the last page loads in the UI. Can anyone analyze the code and tell me what exactly to restructure is so that it displays the first page?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEoGX.png)

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Loads the invoice in the UI, with its associated data.
    /// </summary>
    private void ShowImFromPDF()
    {
        IoC.Main.InvoiceCount = IoC.Main.Invoices.Count;

        GlobalVars.WriteLog("Updating image and data");
        if (IoC.Main.InvoiceIndex >= 0 && IoC.Main.InvoiceIndex < IoC.Main.Invoices.Count)
        {
            IoC.Main.LoadInfo = true;
            PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(IoC.Main.Invoices[IoC.Main.InvoiceIndex].Path);

            foreach (PdfPage page in document.Pages)
            {
                foreach (System.Drawing.Image image in page.GetImages())
                {
                    pictureBox1.Source = HelperMethods.ToBitMapImage(image);
                }
            }
```

Comment: its looks like the `foreach` loop override all images that why it seems you get the last picture, you should use something like `page.GetImages().FirstOrDefualt`

Comment: @styx .FirstOrDefault wont operate on a foreach loop. i am getting this error.

Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'?

Comment: no i mean remove the foreach loop and write instead page.GetImages().FirstOrDefault()

Comment: But that can also return null which i don't want.

Comment: you can get null in the `foreach` loop, if you are afraid for null you can always check if the value is not null with `?` opreator

Comment: @styx I am very new to development, would it be okay for you to elaborate on how to use the FirstOrDefault?

Answer (score 0):

As i wrote in my comment
its looks like the `foreach` loop override all images that why it seems you get the last picture, you should use something like `page.GetImages().FirstOrDefault()`
i mean that you iterate over all pages in the pdf and all images inside your pages and put each one to the same `pictureBox`

How to use FirstOrDefault:

this gets a list of nullable ints, meaning the item can be int or null

```
 public static void doStuff(List<int?> nullableList)
        {            

            var firstItem = nullableList.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstItem != null)
                Console.WriteLine(firstItem);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("first item is null");
        }
```

sending example

```
   List<int?> nullableList = new List<int?>() { 1, null, 2, 3, null };
   doStuff(nullableList);

    List<int?> nullableList1 = new List<int?>() { null, null, 2, 3, null };
    doStuff(nullableList1);
```

result

> 1
>
> "first item is null"

depends on your logic you should get the x image from the y page